# Is a “Load DATA” without a file (i.e., in memory) possible for MySQL and c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to insert about 80k row in sec to mysql server.
currently I use regular INSERT.

I want try  to use LOAD DATA
but I want LOAD data from memory(RAM).
and not from file,that I have to wrtie 
to file and load it from mysqld.

Is any way to do that? 
currently my system run on windows7

Herzl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a file but since the content is in memory you can create a [ram disk](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/) and write the file there, it will be very fast

Another solution is to use a [memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) so you will have the data in memory but you will have it also on disk (the OS guarantees that).

Comment: how i can do it on wondow7 by vc++

Comment: you have different 3rd parties software for this (ex : http://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/) but i do not know how well they behave... on linux the ram-disk is a built-in feature

Comment: i've added another solution pls review it

Comment: taking into account that the OS is win i would say that memory mapped files is the way to go :)

Comment: exist any momoery mapped example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30418/discussion-between-herzl-shemuelian-and-stephan)